# example of overlay view with UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, overlay, uiactivityindicatorview

Does somebody have a good example of adding an overlay view (that covers the whole screen) with an activity indicator in the middle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. I created a semi-transparent view in IB with an activity indicator in the middle. I'm adding it to a tabController.selectedView. When done - removing it from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the [MBProgressHUD](http://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD) framework

Comment: I need a semi-transparent view that covers the whole screen + an activity indicator view in the middle of the screen. I didn't have much success with MSProgressHUD. Do you have example of that?